# Multiple solutions using same database which has sql server project - how to manage source control

Tags: visual-studio, svn, sql-server-data-tools

I use subversion to manage code projects, using a repository structure shown below. Currently, we have a project (lets call it Project A) that includes some sql code within a visual studio sql server project.  Project A isn't being worked on at the moment.  Everything that was being worked on has been merged back to its trunk. Well, now other projects B, C & D need to make changes to that sql code independently.  While those projects never intend to affect project A, there is always that chance (via FK references etc).

What is a good way to manage this situation?  Im thinking that the sql code now needs to be its own project folder in the repo.

```
RepositoryRoot
|
|___ProjectA
    |__branches
        |__dev
        |__local
    |__tags
        |__local
        |__dev
    |__trunk
|___ProjectB
    |__branches
        |__dev
        |__local
    |__tags
        |__local
        |__dev
    |__trunk
|___DatabaseProject ???
    |__branches
        |__dev
        |__local
    |__tags
        |__local
        |__dev
    |__trunk
```

[ **update** ]
So thinking on this a bit further, its not that much more difficult to manage multiple branches of the DB project folder.  However, the dependent references from the application projects are what was bugging me.

A scenario could easily come up where project A changes something while project B nobody is even talking about, let alone actively being worked on. So the database changes along with the updates needed in A, dont get reflected in B until possibly weeks or months later when someone wants to actually make a change to B, but upon opening the project - it wont build because of conflicts.

There are other scenarios, but the above is just one sample.

So the way Im approaching this is to use a combination of TeamCity and SqlPackage to automate builds.  A build of both the application(s) and the database will "connect" everything together to catch issues that would go unseen until later when it would create a real mess.

Comment: So are these other projects referencing ProjectA or creating code completely separate/apart from ProjectA?  If they're referencing ProjectA, they should branch A, make their changes, and update the DB Reference. If they're separate, you need to figure out whether it's worth the time/effort to push those changes back to A and test/release them.

Comment: A and B are independent projects.  However, they interact with the same database.  This database is managed with a VS SQL project, and as such its objects are under source control also.  However, until now this project was part of the same solution with A.  Now I have moved it (the SQL project) into its own project folder within SVN.

Comment: In that case, my general practice would be to branch DB A/B and also branch the shared DB if you're going to make changes to something it hosts. Commit/merge both when done and use a DB reference for Shared DB from DB A/B.  You might have to build Shared to generate a new dacpac to reference the change properly. -- Even in the same solution, I'd do something similar - make changes to the shared DB and commit.

Comment: The A and B projects are not database projects, but rather application projects that reference the same database.  Before B came along, it was just A and its database, which was all at the (SVN) project folder level.   Now, Ive moved the DB code out into its own SVN project folder.  Where I was stuck at was how to manage changes required by A & B on the database, which could possibly include overlapping sql object changes (eg.  table def or procedures).  Yes, I agree with your suggestion regarding separate branches for the DB project folder.  Ive also looked at using a build server (teamcity)